# UDPClient ошибка 10052

Tags: .net, сеть, udp

Есть задача опроса многих (тысячи) устройств по UDP (устройства в GPRS).
Решил воспользоваться классом UDPClient.
Использую функции асинхронного чтения и записи ReceiveAsync, SendAsync, которые возвращают Task-и, через которые можно ждать завершения операции и читать результат.

Алгоритм простой: есть фоновый поток, который в бесконечном цикле рассылает запросы из входящей очереди, а так же читает сокет на предмет входящих данных и выпихивает их в выходную очередь.

После отсылки пакетов на ряд адресов вызов ReceiveAsync завершается Task-ом c выставленным IsFaulted и в Task.Exception у него лежит такая вот гадость:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The connection has been broken due
>   to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while the operation was in
>   progress at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceiveFrom(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, EndPoint& endPoint) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   IPEndPoint& remoteEP) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.b__4(IAsyncResult ar) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)

В [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx)написано, что:

> For a datagram socket, this error indicates that the time to live has
>   expired.

Причем, если после этого вызвать ReceiveAsync, то уже при вызове вылетает точно такое же исключение, приходятся пересоздавать UDPClient.

Собственно вопроса 3:

1. Можно ли избежать таких ошибок? 
   Дело в том, что я такую же программу писал на Delphi, на компоненте UDPServer из Indy 9 и там было все замечательно, при опросе того же самого оборудования в той же сети. Я собственно даже никаких ошибок не видел. От отвалившихся устройств просто ничего не приходило.
2. Как понять для какого пакета (IPEndPoint) вышел TTL. Запросы одновременно могут посылаться в сотни адресов.
3. В случае ошибки, можно ли продолжить работу, не не переоткрывая Socket?

Проблемно значимый код выглядит приблизительно так:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Основаная процедура ввода/вывода 
    /// </summary>
    private void DoIO()
    {
        Task<UdpReceiveResult> readResult = null;
        Task<int> writeResult = null;
        //0 - чтение
        //1 - запись или сигнал о поступлениях во входящей очереди
        WaitHandle[] waitedEvents = new WaitHandle[2];
        RequestInfo? request = null;
        while (true)
            try
            {
                // Чтение всегда должно быть
                if (readResult == null)
                {
                    readResult = _udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
                    waitedEvents[0] = (readResult as IAsyncResult).AsyncWaitHandle;
                }
                // Достаем очередной запрос 
                if (!request.HasValue)
                {
                    request = ExtractRequest();
                    writeResult = null;
                }

                // Отправка запроса, с паралельной задачей чтения 
                if (request.HasValue)
                {
                    if (writeResult == null)
                        writeResult = _udpClient.SendAsync(request.Value.Data,
                                                            request.Value.Data.Length,
                                                            request.Value.Connection.IpEndPoint);
                    waitedEvents[1] = (writeResult as IAsyncResult).AsyncWaitHandle;

                    if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitedEvents) == 1) // Завершилась задача записи 
                    {
                        if (writeResult.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            request.Value.Connection.AddMessage(writeResult.Exception.Message);
                            throw new Exception("Ошибка записи", writeResult.Exception);
                        }
                        writeResult.Dispose();
                        writeResult = null;
                        request = null;
                    }
                }
                else // Чтение и ожидание нового пакета на отправку
                {
                    waitedEvents[1] = eventNewRequest;
                    WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitedEvents);
                }

                //чтение завершено 
                if (readResult.IsCompleted)
                {
                    if (readResult.IsFaulted)
                        throw new Exception("Ошибка чтения", readResult.Exception);
                    else
                        SendResponse(readResult);
                    readResult.Dispose();
                    readResult = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                AppendDiagnosticMessage(null, DiagnosticMessageKindData.Error, e.Message);
                if (readResult != null)
                {
                    if (readResult.IsCompleted)
                        readResult.Dispose();
                    readResult = null;
                }
                if (writeResult != null)
                {
                    if (writeResult.IsCompleted)
                        writeResult.Dispose();
                    writeResult = null;
                }
                DisposeUdpClient(true);
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Запускает поток ввода/вывода если еще не запущен
    /// </summary>
    private void StartIOThreadIfNeed()
    {
        lock (this)
            if (_udpClient == null)
            {
                _udpClient = CreateUdpClient();
                new Thread(DoIO) {IsBackground = true}.Start();
            }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создает объект обмен по UDP
    /// </summary>
    private UdpClient CreateUdpClient()
    {
        //Пытаемся занять ранее используемый порт, если не выходит, то занимаем какой то новый
        UdpClient result = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            try
            {
                result = new UdpClient(_localPort);
                _localPort = ((IPEndPoint)result.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;
                break;
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                if (e.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.AddressAlreadyInUse && _localPort != 0)
                    _localPort = 0;
                else
                    throw;
            }
        var socket = result.Client;
        socket.SendBufferSize = 0xFFFF;
        socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 0xFFFF;
        result.Ttl = 255;                    
        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Удаляет UDPClient
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recreate">Пересоздать объект</param>
    private void DisposeUdpClient(bool recreate = false)
    {
        lock (this)
            if (_udpClient != null)
                try
                {
                    (_udpClient as IDisposable).Dispose();
                    _udpClient = null;
                    if (recreate)
                        _udpClient = CreateUdpClient();
                }
                catch
                { 
                };
    }
```

Comment: Хм. А покажите, пожалуйста, код. То есть не весь, а то, что важно для вопроса (желательно поменьше).

Comment: @VladD Добил код в основное сообщение

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь async/await? Ожидание через хэндл — жутко низкоуровневый подход.

Comment: У вас сложная логика, которую мне трудно «выловить» из вашего кода. Может, объясните на словах, что должен делать код?

Comment: @VladD Мне казалось я понятно написал. Попробую подробнее. Из внешнего потока поступают запросы на отправку. Запрос это байтовый массив и целевая точка доставки (адрес и порт). При добавлении запроса в очередь внешний поток поднимает событие eventNewRequest.  Рабочий поток ввода/вывода извлекает задание из очереди функцией ExtractRequest и отсылает по целевому адресу. Так же поток читает  сокет на предмет входных данных и отправляет их для обработки во внешний поток  функцией  SendResponse. Я правда не особенно понимаю какое то отношение имеет к заданным вопросам. .

Comment: Я хочу попробовать написать более простой код с async/await, возможно, в нём будет проще отловить ошибку.

Comment: @VladD Мне кажется  вы не совсем внимательно прочитали вопрос. В коде ошибок нет (точнее они конечно есть, но дело не в них). Проблема в том, что при чтении сокета возникает ошибка связанная с доставкой одного из пакетов. Ошибка связана не с моей программой, а с доставкой пакета по стеку протоколов. У одного из пакетов выходит TTL. Вопросы я перечислил. Я думаю может как то можно настроить сокет, что бы он эту ошибку игнорировал либо путь ошибка возникает, но хотелось бы продолжить работу с сокетом. Сейчас мне приходится его разрушать и создавать заново. Ввиду большого траффика я теряю данные.

Comment: Ну, я надеялся, что а async/await можно будет поймать проблему _в точности_ в момент её возникновения, и таким образом избежать потери данных

Comment: Кстати, Microsoft'овский пример [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) пересоздаёт `UdpClient` для нового хоста.

Comment: С учётом этого основная логика выглядела бы так: http://pastebin.com/k9NzP6ug

Comment: @VladD То, что в примерах Microsoft, это конечно замечательно. В первой версии я тоже создавал отдельный соке на каждый хост. Проблема в том, что у меня сейчас этих хостов ~7000 и их число будет рости. Это чудовищно нерациональное  расходование ресурсов ядра ОС, кода можно обойтись всего одним сокетом.
Не хочется быть не вежливым, я понимаю ваше желание помочь, но к сожалению вы вместо решения обозначенных проблем пытаетесь переписать код через ваш любимый async/await. Проблема лежит не в многопоточности, а в использовании сокетов.  Судя по коду их вы понимаете еще хуже меня.

Comment: Если вы разбираетесь лучше меня в сокетах, возможно, вам стоит подождать совета от кого-то ещё.

Comment: Если нужно опростить большое количество хостов(устройств) на предмет открытости портов или присутствия в сети, то сокеты это гиблое дело!! Они слишком медленные и не рациональные для этого. Я бы посоветовал использовать WinPcap (под винду) и ли Libpcap (под линуху) сетевой  драйвер с его помощью  я генерирую до 500000 запросов в секунду и в зависимости от таймаута  получаю ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно опростить большое количество хостов (устройств) на предмет открытости портов или присутствия в сети, то сокеты — гиблое дело: они слишком медленные и не рациональные для этого.

Я бы посоветовал использовать [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) (под *ms/windows*) или [Libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (под *gnu/linux*).

С его помощью я генерирую до 500000 запросов в секунду, и в зависимости от таймаута получаю ответы.

---

ответ взят из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418150/udpclient-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-10052#comment432547_418150), оставленного [IGOR](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2988)